# Sum subset of a variable for tidy data r

Tags: r

I want to sum a subset of categories contained within a single variable, organized as tidy data in r.

It seems like it should be simple, but I can only think of a large number of lines of code to do it.

Here is an example:

```
df = data.frame(food = c("carbs", "protein", "apple", "pear"), value = c(10, 12, 4, 3))
df
     food value
1   carbs    10
2 protein    12
3   apple     4
4    pear     3
```

I want the data frame to look like this (combining apple and pear into fruit):

```
     food value
1   carbs    10
2 protein    12
3   fruit     7
```

The way I can think to do this is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
spread(key = "food", value = "value") %>%
mutate(fruit = apple + pear) %>%
select(-c(apple, pear)) %>%
gather(key = "food", value = "value")

     food value
1   carbs    10
2 protein    12
3   fruit     7
```

This seems too long for something so simple. I could also subset the data, sum the rows and then rbind, but that also seems laborious.

Any quicker options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A factor can be recoded with `forcats::fct_recode` but this isn't necessarily shorter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>%
  mutate(food = fct_recode(food, fruit = 'apple', fruit = 'pear')) %>%
  group_by(food) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  food    value
#  <fct>   <dbl>
#1 fruit       7
#2 carbs      10
#3 protein    12
```

**Edit.**

I will post the code in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680163/sum-subset-of-a-variable-for-tidy-data-r/57680354#comment101807385_57680354) here, since comments are more often deleted than answers. The result is the same as above.

```
df %>%
  group_by(food = fct_recode(food, fruit = 'apple', fruit = 'pear')) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value))
```

Comment: You can further shorten it by `group_by(food = fct_recode(food, fruit = 'apple', fruit = 'pear'))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk Thanks, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
df %>%
 group_by(food = if_else(food %in% c("apple", "pear"), "fruit", food)) %>%
 summarise_all(sum)

  food    value
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 carbs      10
2 fruit       7
3 protein    12
```